# Why my 64 bit server is slow when running PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos

I have 64 bit server with 6GB RAM and proc xeon E5620 installed with centos server 64. But when I access my localhost php application, is a little bit slow than run on my localhost old laptop. Did I miss some configuration?

In that server I am use PHP 5.1.2 and Mysql 5.0.77.

Thanks

Comment: That is an *ancient* configuration. Did you consider upgrading to something more recent? Also, profile your code and see where the bottlenecks are - disk access? Database? Number crunching (probably not this one)? Fast processor and lots of RAM are useless if your bottleneck is elsewhere (e.g. disk access).

Comment: Was Apache by any chance doing reverse lookups on ip addresses for logging?

Answer (score 0):

What type of application are you using ? Check if your DNS is correct, or if there is some reverse resolutions which are pending.